# Good tools for drawing schematics

Tags: schematics, cad, eda, education

I was going to add a bit of information to my post on a previous day using schematics and some instructions. What programs are being employed for this purpose?

I mostly want to see what others are using and that I can easily use to give descriptive schematics.

In a perfect world, and I know this is a case of me wishing, it would be:

1. Free.
2. Extremely easy to draw schematics
   in.
3. Allows simple production of
   waveforms for the inputs/outputs.

Comment: Older comments  [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118578/discussion-on-question-by-kortuk-good-tools-for-drawing-schematics).

Comment: SE's aim is to provide high quality Q&A sets that will drive search engine traffic to the site. - I have reopened this question as it demonstrably meets that aim and is of considerable use and interest to many. Despite its age it provides current and useful information. | . It was closed more than 5 years after being asked with literally dozens of high quality answers. More answers were added over the intervening years. I accessed about 50! of the links in answers and comments and only two were dead - the rest lead to the material that you'd expect.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon **[This official webpage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)** says questions shouldn't be about "programming software for a PC."

Comment: @Alejandro Nava It does. Fortunately this is not that. It does however fit the requirements for a useful question, as noted in my reopening comment above. It now has 37 answers which are mostly good quality and useful and liable to attract search engine traffic.

Comment: “Fortunately this is not that.” // This question is about software for PC. While they’re not programming software, they’re still software, for drawing schematics. Furthermore, this question asks about *suggestions*, which makes it impossible to select an answer as best answer, which (as far as I know) goes against this website’s policies.

Answer (score 106):

Try [KiCAD](https://www.kicad.org/). Now it even does [SPICE simulations](https://thestumbler.io/projs/modelrr/03-spice-and-kicad.html), `ngspice` specifically, and it handles pretty much everything else. Other than that, if you wish, KiCAD has also the tools to design printed circuit boards, and even has a 3D viewer and exporter for the boards!

KiCAD runs on Windows, Linux and Apple OS X.

There is also a project called [ESIM](http://esim.fossee.in//) that bundles KiCAD with a SPICE simulator and differential equation solver.

Comment: Despite it's UI, Kicad is really quite powerful for the price (free) - 16 layer boards, Gerber export and no limit on board size.

Comment: @DoxaLogos, For making a schematic or PCB, it is actually very easy to get accustomed to. Is there any way to get more parts added, or do I need to add them myself?

Comment: Peter, you say "despite its UI". Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Kortuk, It has some libraries you can download, but I think most you'll have to add them yourself.

Comment: @Kortuk: I couldn't figure out how to add parts either, so I asked: ["How do I install a KiCad schematic or footprint library?"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/how-do-i-install-a-kicad-schematic-or-footprint-library/)

Comment: And on top of it: "Kicad runs on Windows, Linux and Apple OS X and is released under the open-source GNU GPL v2"

Comment: KiCAD is not usable. The authors of KiCAD need to go find a 1984 vintage Apple Macintosh, use it for a few weeks, and then redesign the user interface.

Comment: As always..usability is a matter of opinion. At the time I used it, I didn't have much trouble. Only problem was the lack of depth in the parts library.

Comment: As of this date, KiCAD has quite an extensive library, and its UI is easy once you get used to it (actually adding components by typing their names instead of looking for them in a thumbnails list has proven very efficient)

Comment: It doesn't have a simple DC voltage source symbol ... how come?

Comment: FYI: KiCad recently added SPICE simulation with NGspice under the hood. Sample tutorial here: http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/ngspice-eeschema.html

Answer (score 75):

My favorite schematic capture tool is a pencil on green-gridded engineering paper, and a camera.

Once I have the schematic how I like it, it goes into gschem.

But for just sketching up circuits, paper is the way to go.

[image: linear drivers rock]

Comment: I keep a field notebook around for that.  It comes gridded, with ruled pages opposite for notes.  It's also water-resistant, so if it comes with you everywhere and you live in a rainy climate there's an extra level of protection.

Comment: I have design journals around that look the same, but I doubt my boss would enjoy me jotting down things for chiphacker in them.

Comment: Point taken on the picture, I wish I always had paper with me. I also wish my handwriting was readable.

Comment: This is what I do at work, too.  I just scribble something down, take a picture of it, and email it to the factory.  :)

Comment: I use a scanner (better quality for line drawings than camera) + paper/pencil. Looks great!

Comment: That takes me back - similar to all those old Radio Shack books by Forrest Mims III...

Comment: That looks stunningly like my writing and drawing style. Are you OK :-)

Comment: And now with the convenience of Google Photos and modern smartphones, once you take a picture it is instantly loaded up online on your google photos account at http://www.photos.google.com. Makes saving it on the computer or inserting into a document sooo much easier.

Comment: Is this DaveCad?

Comment: Green-gridded engineering paper appears to be difficult to purchase in the UK, the nearest thing is blue graph paper which is very common: https://static.rapidonline.com/catalogueimages/product/06/00/s06-0077p01wl.jpg

Answer (score 55):

And now you can do that inside a reasonably modern browser with [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/).

The community version, <strike>which is free</strike>, is somewhat limited on its library of components, but the simulator running in the browser is a testament to the power of current JavaScript engines.

*Update Jan 2015: CircuitLab is not free anymore; there's only a time-limited demo without a save feature. There are commercial and non-commercial plans available. For students whose university has an academical license, use is free of charge. See [all plans](https://www.circuitlab.com/accounts/upgrade/). The embedded CircuitLab here on EE.SE is still available free of charge.*

This is an example screenshot of the Circuitlab design environment:

[image]

This is an example screenshot of the Circuitlab simulation environment:

[image]

Comment: CircuitLab is now embedded into Electronics Stack Exchange! http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/963/embedding-a-schematic-editor

Comment: That simulation plot sure is ugly.

Comment: (CircuitLab co-founder here.) Fortunately we've made the simulation plots much nicer looking since then: see https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/wt3nym/ to try this RLC resonance example. We do have partnerships with many universities now, making it free for their students and faculty. And we'd appreciate other feedback from the EE.SE community!

Answer (score 48):

Another option is [KTechlab](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ktechlab/).  I suspect most people have never heard of it, but it's a free electronics simulation program that lets you do simple circuits.  Schematics are easy to draw and it produces waveforms easily.  I find it more intuitive and quick than a SPICE simulator, but of course it's not as powerful.  It's more a system for thinking about idealized circuits, while SPICE is more a system for modeling real-life circuits, along with all their flaws and frailties.  It's Linux-only, but you can run it in Virtualbox or something.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks interesting.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you can use it as an IDE too for programming the chips you design into your circuit.

Comment: I've never used that part.  :)

Comment: Interesting! I really have never heard of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 40):

[gschem](http://www.gpleda.org/tools/gschem/index.html) of [geda](http://www.gpleda.org/) makes nice schematics, with real fonts.

1. It's free software (GPL license).
2. It's as easy as it gets. All the schematic capture programs need some learning.
3. I've not tried that, but there ought to be something in the gEDA suite.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will take a look at it.

Comment: WOW have never heard about geda, did an apt-get and checking it out now.  Really cool, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Since 'me' resurrected this thread with the Webtronix program a few hours ago, I thought I'd add for future reference that gEDA does include the Icarus and GTKWave simulators.  These take more work than an LTSpice simulation (You either have to add simulation data to all the parts you use, or write up a Verilog simulation), but gEDA (Unlike most PCB design packages) definitely does have a simulator.

Comment: There is also gnuspice and ngspice. Really, simulation and schematic capture are two separate problems, and it would be better to consider them separately. There's hardly a schematic or simulation tool out there that doesn't speak a common netlist format.

Answer (score 34):

This [Java circuit simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/) is pretty easy to draw schematics in, and it has a way to export them as plain text:

```
$ 1 5.0E-6 0.9891409633455756 46 5.0 50
I 240 256 304 256 0 0.5
I 352 256 416 256 0 0.5
w 416 256 416 192 0
w 240 192 240 256 0
r 320 272 320 336 0 220000.0
c 320 352 320 400 0 4.7000000000000004E-8 1.4535908873993098
g 320 416 320 432 0
s 224 384 224 320 0 1 true
w 240 256 224 256 0
w 224 256 224 320 0
w 272 384 224 384 0
w 320 352 320 336 0
w 320 400 320 416 0
w 272 384 272 352 0
w 272 352 320 352 0
w 304 256 320 272 0
w 352 256 320 272 0
r 240 192 416 192 0 5000.0
o 1 64 0 35 5.0 0.0015625 0 -1
```

The above code will produce this circuit:

[image: two-inverter momentary toggle]

Maybe there's a way to integrate it into a site, so that users can draw a circuit, paste the above code into the answer box, surround it with special tags, and it will create a pop-up applet?

Even better, a schematic image could be generated from the code, which, when clicked on, opens a simulation applet of that schematic.

Maybe talk to the author about something like this?  He has the applet zipped up for you to use on your own computer, but I don't know about distributing it on other websites.

**Update:** I talked to the author, and he implemented URL data within hours of me proposing it.  There is now an "Export Link" menu option that generates links like this, without requiring a directory or hashtable on the server or anything.  You can use the same URL to display the same circuit while using the java file on your own computer:

[This should display the above circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+0.9891409633455756+70+5+50%0AI+240+256+304+256+0+0.5+5%0AI+352+256+416+256+0+0.5+5%0Aw+416+256+416+192+0%0Aw+240+192+240+256+0%0Ar+320+272+320+336+0+220000%0Ac+320+352+320+400+0+4.7000000000000004e-8+2.5726297800458404%0Ag+320+416+320+432+0%0As+224+384+224+320+0+1+true%0Aw+240+256+224+256+0%0Aw+224+256+224+320+0%0Aw+272+384+224+384+0%0Aw+320+352+320+336+0%0Aw+320+400+320+416+0%0Aw+272+384+272+352+0%0Aw+272+352+320+352+0%0Aw+304+256+320+272+0%0Aw+352+256+320+272+0%0Ar+240+192+416+192+0+5000%0AO+416+256+448+256+0%0Ao+5+64+0+4099+5+0.0015625+0+2+5+3%0Ao+18+64+0+4098+5+0.1+1+1%0A)

And he pointed out [the licensing agreement](http://www.falstad.com/licensing.html), which I think permits us to modify it and use it on here to embed schematics, like [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-capseries.html).

> You have permission to modify the applets and/or copy the applets onto your own web site as long as you credit me (Paul Falstad) and provide a link to my page

This 4000 character URL should show a [7-segment decoder](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%203%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0AL%20240%2040%20240%2016%202%200%20false%205%200%0AL%20288%2040%20288%2016%202%201%20false%205%200%0AL%20336%2040%20336%2016%202%200%20false%205%200%0AL%20384%2040%20384%2016%202%201%20false%205%200%0AI%20240%2040%20240%2088%200%200.5%205%0AI%20288%2040%20288%2088%200%200.5%205%0AI%20336%2040%20336%2088%200%200.5%205%0AI%20384%2040%20384%2088%200%200.5%205%0Aw%20288%2040%20312%2040%200%0Aw%20312%2040%20312%20104%200%0A151%2040%20176%2040%20224%201%204%205%205%0A151%2096%20176%2096%20224%201%203%205%205%0A151%20152%20176%20152%20224%201%202%205%205%0A151%20208%20176%20208%20224%201%204%205%205%0A151%20568%20176%20568%20224%201%203%205%205%0A151%20520%20176%20520%20224%201%203%200%205%0A151%20472%20176%20472%20224%201%203%205%205%0A151%20424%20176%20424%20224%201%203%205%205%0A151%20368%20176%20368%20224%201%203%205%205%0A150%20272%20176%20272%20224%201%202%200%205%0A152%20320%20176%20320%20224%201%202%205%205%0Aw%20312%20104%2088%20104%200%0Aw%2088%20104%2088%20176%200%0Aw%20312%20104%20480%20104%200%0Aw%20480%20104%20528%20104%200%0Aw%20528%20104%20576%20104%200%0Aw%20576%20104%20576%20176%200%0Aw%20528%20176%20528%20104%200%0Aw%20480%20176%20480%20104%200%0Aw%20336%2040%20360%2040%200%0Aw%20360%2040%20360%20112%200%0Aw%20160%20176%20160%20112%200%0Aw%2096%20176%2096%20112%200%0Aw%2096%20112%20160%20112%200%0Aw%20160%20112%20360%20112%200%0Aw%20360%20112%20424%20112%200%0Aw%20424%20112%20424%20176%200%0Aw%20424%20112%20568%20112%200%0Aw%20568%20112%20568%20176%200%0Aw%20384%2040%20408%2040%200%0Aw%20408%2040%20408%20120%200%0Aw%20408%20120%20520%20120%200%0Aw%20520%20120%20520%20176%200%0Aw%20408%20120%20376%20120%200%0Aw%20376%20176%20376%20120%200%0Aw%20376%20120%20224%20120%200%0Aw%20224%20120%20224%20176%200%0Aw%20224%20120%20104%20120%200%0Aw%20104%20120%20104%20176%200%0Aw%20240%2088%20240%20128%200%0Aw%20240%20128%20216%20128%200%0Aw%20216%20128%20216%20176%200%0Aw%20216%20128%2024%20128%200%0Aw%2024%20128%2024%20176%200%0Aw%20240%20128%20328%20128%200%0Aw%20328%20128%20328%20176%200%0Aw%20288%2088%20288%20136%200%0Aw%20280%20176%20280%20136%200%0Aw%20280%20136%20288%20136%200%0Aw%20200%20176%20200%20136%200%0Aw%20280%20136%20200%20136%200%0Aw%20200%20136%20144%20136%200%0Aw%20144%20136%20144%20176%200%0Aw%20144%20136%2032%20136%200%0Aw%2032%20136%2032%20176%200%0Aw%20288%20136%20360%20136%200%0Aw%20360%20136%20360%20176%200%0Aw%20360%20136%20432%20136%200%0Aw%20432%20136%20432%20176%200%0Aw%20336%2088%20336%20144%200%0Aw%20336%20144%20368%20144%200%0Aw%20368%20144%20368%20176%200%0Aw%20368%20144%20472%20144%200%0Aw%20472%20144%20472%20176%200%0Aw%20336%20144%20264%20144%200%0Aw%20264%20144%20264%20176%200%0Aw%20264%20144%20192%20144%200%0Aw%20192%20144%20192%20176%200%0Aw%20192%20144%2048%20144%200%0Aw%2048%20144%2048%20176%200%0Aw%20384%2088%20384%20152%200%0Aw%20472%20144%20512%20144%200%0Aw%20512%20144%20512%20176%200%0Aw%20384%20152%20416%20152%200%0Aw%20416%20152%20416%20176%200%0Aw%20416%20152%20464%20152%200%0Aw%20464%20152%20464%20176%200%0Aw%20464%20152%20560%20152%200%0Aw%20560%20152%20560%20176%200%0Aw%20384%20152%20240%20152%200%0Aw%20240%20152%2056%20152%200%0Aw%2056%20152%2056%20176%200%0Aw%20272%20224%20296%20224%200%0Aw%20296%20224%20296%20176%200%0Aw%20296%20176%20312%20176%200%0A150%2056%20288%2056%20336%201%204%205%205%0A150%20232%20288%20232%20336%201%204%205%205%0A150%20384%20288%20384%20336%201%204%205%205%0A150%20336%20288%20336%20336%201%203%200%205%0A150%20288%20288%20288%20336%201%202%205%205%0A150%20176%20288%20176%20336%201%203%200%205%0A150%20120%20288%20120%20336%201%204%205%205%0Aw%2040%20224%2040%20288%200%0Aw%20240%20152%20240%20232%200%0Aw%20240%20232%20168%20232%200%0Aw%20168%20232%20168%20288%200%0Aw%20176%20288%20176%20240%200%0Aw%20176%20240%20240%20240%200%0Aw%20240%20240%20240%20288%200%0Aw%20240%20240%20400%20240%200%0Aw%20400%20240%20400%20288%200%0Aw%20400%20240%20472%20240%200%0Aw%20472%20240%20472%20224%200%0Aw%20184%20288%20184%20256%200%0Aw%20184%20256%20128%20256%200%0Aw%20128%20256%20128%20288%200%0Aw%20128%20256%2064%20256%200%0Aw%2064%20256%2064%20288%200%0Aw%2048%20288%2048%20248%200%0Aw%2072%20288%2072%20264%200%0Aw%2072%20264%20136%20264%200%0Aw%20136%20264%20136%20288%200%0Aw%2048%20248%2096%20248%200%0Aw%2096%20248%2096%20224%200%0Aw%2096%20248%20112%20248%200%0Aw%20112%20248%20112%20288%200%0Aw%20152%20224%20152%20232%200%0Aw%20152%20232%20104%20232%200%0Aw%20104%20232%20104%20288%200%0Aw%20392%20288%20392%20248%200%0Aw%20392%20248%20344%20248%200%0Aw%20344%20248%20344%20288%200%0Aw%20392%20248%20568%20248%200%0Aw%20568%20248%20568%20224%200%0Aw%20112%20248%20224%20248%200%0Aw%20224%20248%20224%20288%200%0Aw%20184%20256%20216%20256%200%0Aw%20216%20256%20216%20288%200%0Aw%20208%20224%20208%20264%200%0Aw%20136%20264%20208%20264%200%0Aw%20208%20264%20368%20264%200%0Aw%20368%20264%20368%20288%200%0Aw%20376%20288%20376%20256%200%0Aw%20376%20256%20328%20256%200%0Aw%20328%20256%20328%20288%200%0Aw%20328%20256%20280%20256%200%0Aw%20280%20256%20280%20288%200%0Aw%20320%20224%20328%20224%200%0Aw%20328%20224%20328%20256%200%0Aw%20280%20256%20216%20256%200%0Aw%20248%20288%20248%20232%200%0Aw%20248%20232%20368%20232%200%0Aw%20368%20232%20368%20224%200%0Aw%20296%20288%20296%20272%200%0Aw%20296%20272%20424%20272%200%0Aw%20424%20272%20424%20224%200%0Aw%20336%20288%20336%20280%200%0Aw%20336%20280%20520%20280%200%0Aw%20520%20280%20520%20224%200%0A157%20432%20320%20552%20320%200%0Aw%20432%20320%20416%20320%200%0Aw%20416%20320%20416%20336%200%0Aw%20416%20336%20384%20336%200%0Aw%20432%20352%20336%20352%200%0Aw%20336%20352%20336%20336%200%0Aw%20432%20384%20288%20384%200%0Aw%20288%20384%20288%20336%200%0Aw%20432%20416%20232%20416%200%0Aw%20232%20416%20232%20336%200%0Aw%20496%20448%20176%20448%200%0Aw%20176%20448%20176%20336%200%0Aw%20528%20448%20528%20456%200%0Aw%20528%20456%20120%20456%200%0Aw%20120%20456%20120%20336%200%0Aw%20560%20448%20560%20464%200%0Aw%20560%20464%2056%20464%200%0Aw%2056%20464%2056%20336%200%0A)

Comment: I think you should flag this up on Meta (unfortunately I'm on my phone so the simulation applet doesn't work).

Comment: What do you mean "flag it up"?

Comment: 4000 character URLs!?

Comment: That's one of the most complicated circuits in the examples.  Internet Explorer only accepts 2000 characters, unfortunately.  :)

Comment: @endolith I want to download it in my laptop. But I couldn't find it. Can you please provide me a link or steps to download it?

Comment: @KrishnShweta I don't know how to download the javascript version, but the java applet can be downloaded

Comment: @endolith Oh OK! It's fine. I'll use online one. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 33):

For more limited media there's AACircuit - source code now at https://github.com/Andy1978/AACircuit, binaries from http://tech-chat.de/download.php

```
                        ___
                   .---|___|-----.
                   |             |
                   |             |
             ___   |  |\|        |
           -|___|-----|-\        |
                      |  >-------'
                   .--|+/
                   |  |/|
                   |    |
                  ===  ===
                  GND  GND
(created by AACircuit v1.28.6 beta 04/19/05 www.tech-chat.de)
```

Comment: I have to admit, that is quite fun.

Comment: This is a cool idea since you can't upload files to this site... So a small ascii-art can probably help showing some simple things :)

Comment: It seems to work with wine under Ubuntu as well.

Comment: I have now used it, and for just throwing a schematic together, awesome!

Comment: Looks awesome! But the web site is all in german!

Comment: The link is dead. Can anyone update please?

Comment: I'm the author and moved the site to a new server (not uploaded the pages yet). And I've released the sourcecode: https://github.com/Andy1978/AACircuit So you can grab the code and compile it yourself with Delphi or propably Lazarus

Comment: The original pages are back: http://tech-chat.de/download.php and I've made a new binary release (compiled source from github) with a bigger drawing area

Answer (score 31):

[TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) can be used to generate publication-quality schematics.  [Here are some examples.](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/area/electrical-engineering/)

> [CircuiTikz](http://web.archive.org/web/20090605170624/http://home.dei.polimi.it/mredaelli/circuitikz/examples.html) is a set of LaTeX macros designed to make it easy to draw electrical networks in scientific publications. It provides a convenient syntax based on to-paths to place the various components.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful circuits!

Comment: I totally agree with @chicks. They look a lot with my text books drawings! :)

Comment: I find Xcircuit is better than this. The symbols need some time to get used to in this.

Answer (score 29):

I personally use [EAGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAGLE_%28program%29), but the learning curve is somewhat high. You might want to check out [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/); it's open source and built with the beginner in mind.

Comment: I know how to do schematics/simulations/layouts and I am not finding this to be the issue. The problem I have had is having one that is very fast to use for when I want to give more detailed answers on chiphacker. I have some time for chiphacker, but not enough to be doing full simulations for questions regularly.

Comment: The simple/intuitive nature of Fritzing will lend itself to your goals I think.  I encourage you to take a look.

Comment: Fritzing seems to have a lot of community potential. If it takes off in the same way as the Arduino project, it could be really great. Right now, it's lacking some essential components, but seems to be moving forward.

Comment: This looks interesting.

Comment: I use it for all my PCB design so useful.

Answer (score 20):

The [same question came up on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aElectronics#Drawing_circuits).

The top recommendation there seems to be Inkscape + a nice collection of public-domain [electrical symbols](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aElectrical_symbols_library.svg) you can download from Wikipedia.

I find that a little surprising, because Inkscape is a general-purpose graphics editor which knows nothing about diagrams or electronics.

Comment: Inkscape outputs SVG images, which is a requirement:
3. It has to be able to export in SVG: the SVG is the format that was proposed by wikipedia for diagrams. It provides the best quality at the minimum space. 
Most schematic capture programs have the same view you took - Graphics as such (other than PDF export) are useless. Wikipedia wants the prettiest, smallest graphics. What we want is different: The fastest, easiest way to create a schematic and its simulation.

Comment: Still an interesting solution

Comment: ktechlab does have (experimental) svg export.

Comment: I came here looking for exactly this: a symbol library in SVG for use with Inkscape.  Thanks!

Comment: Examples of schematics made using this collection: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Created_with_electrical_symbols_library

Comment: Here is another group of symbols meant to be used this way http://www.luciani.org/not-quite-ready/not-quite-ready-index.html#symbols

Comment: I use Inkscape from time to time. It's like pulling teeth, even for simple graphics. For schematics? Yagoddabekidding. All that work, and no netlist, no design checks, ...

Comment: +1 I use this all the time. I have that svg stored on my desktop for easy opening to capture cct that represent reasonably well a concept while not being 100% accurate (ie ideal for presentations/reports)

Comment: I think inkscape is easy to use and powerful.  I wish it supported multi-page so I didn't have to edit PDFs page by page, but otherwise it rocks.  It seems like a natural solution for this problem to me.

Comment: I use inkscape a lot for makeing neat schematics to go into reports, documentation, study material. It's not a tool to make schematics during production, but it's for making them afterwards for documentation purposes. It's sure beats the TeX options for making very neat schematics in books or texts. The best part is that if there is a symbol not in your library, you just draw it and add it! Every single other option I've used, eventually there is some library symbol that either looks off or is just not there.

Answer (score 15):

I use [DipTrace](http://www.diptrace.com/), and I'm very satisfied. It's not free, but it is quite inexpensive. I tried [EAGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAGLE_%28program%29), which seems to be the most widely used, but I was horrified about its unfriendliness.

To me, it's not only a thing about learning curve, but simply making things harder to do than it should be. It made me remember a traumatic experience with [AutoCAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD) during the late 1980s. I tried many other low-cost and free alternatives, but they either were also a bad-UI, unstable, or had a poor component library. The only under-100s package that worked well was DipTrace. Its weakness is that the PCB router is not very efficient (it was unable to route some boards that I was able to route manually without much effort), in particular when you have few layers, but to my use this was a minor limitation in comparison.

Comment: DipTrace is easy to use in a way that's really hard to describe. It's my favorite out of all the packages I've tried.

Comment: Currently diptrace is also available in a 300pin limited freeware according to their site.

Answer (score 14):

Usually whenever I'm doing this, I'd just plop out a circuit in [SPICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE) and then print to a PDF. Not the most elegant solution, but not the most difficult either.

[LTSpice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice) is free and pretty great. Also, I hear they keep waveforms inside some of those circle and triangle things on the schematics; you just need to push some buttons to let them out :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for something like google docs of schematics, as I have never heard of any thing that nice, I thought I would just ask if anyone knew something about it.

Comment: National Webench does a lot, but it's more wizard oriented and doesn't let you lay out circuits. You get to play with parameters and simulation very much like spice, though.

Comment: Update to this is you can use Google Drawing but it's not the BEST option.

Comment: I wrote a little lt2circuitikz script (https://github.com/ckuhlmann/lt2circuitikz) to convert LTspice .asc files to .tex files with circuiTikZ graphics and create nice PDF schematics. It also contains symbols for most of the circuiTikZ library elements for LTspice.
The script is in Python3. Take a look if you use LTspice anyway, might be a good way to get high quality pdf files.

Answer (score 14):

Try [TinyCAD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinycad/): it's open-source. For schematic capture (this doesn't do simulation, although you can export netlists to [PSPICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OrCAD#OrCAD_EE_PSpice)).

(Disclosure of bias: I work with the project maintainer.)

Comment: Looks interesting.

Comment: I have used TinyCAD in production. There was a serious bug with netlist generation but it has since been resolved. TinyCAD works pretty well and is easy to learn.

Comment: the link is broken, here is a correct link : https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinycad/?source=directory (I don't have editing privileges, if someone who does want to update the anwser...)

Answer (score 14):

An option is [Quite Universial Circuit Simulator](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html) (qucs).

(But I'm not sure if it is ready for prime time yet, but so far so good.)

Comment: Yeah. I use this.

Answer (score 14):

[XCircuit](http://opencircuitdesign.com/xcircuit/) is designed for publication-quality diagrams.  It outputs PostScript.  I remember finding the UI awkward and the output a little weird, myself, but it's maybe improved since I last used it, and it's certainly better quality than a screenshot of a schematic capture program.

You can find [some examples of its output on Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=xcircuit).

[image]

Comment: I just gave XCircuit a go. Ughh, the UI is so awkward and terrible. It's probably a great tool, but the UI is just so bad.

Comment: @ChrisZeh, I agree that the interface is 80's (especially the dialogs...), but the quality of the output and the speed you can achieve in drawing outweighs  (at least for me) the steep learning curve... (I use it only on Unix, though. Never managed to use it in windows and without a mouse with middle-click).

Answer (score 13):

Probably not the best solution, but most of time I use Eagle to make schematics. Now, that doesn't really cover points 2 and 3 of your requirements, but it's what I use. Additionally I frequently use OrCad PSPICE.

I would, however, strongly recommend gEDA http://www.gpleda.org/

Comment: Eagle is a good idea too as long as you have the libraries all set up. Plus if you plan to make a board eventually, this would be a good start so you can later get a board layout going.

Comment: I am not planning to make a board, I have programs for doing real schematics and layouts, the problem is that they have a large overhead in my time when it comes to me answering something on this board and require a dongle, which means I do not have them at home.

Answer (score 13):

There's also this web-based thing, meant to have screenshots taken of it:

http://www.qsl.net/wd9eyb/klunky/framed.html

But could it be modified to generate code that could be copied and pasted into this site? Something that generates a single image would be preferable, of course.

[image][image: R]
[image: R][image: npn]
[image][image: R]

There's a real need for a quick web-based schematic drawing tool, not just here, but everywhere. I would code it if I knew how, but my skills are weak. Could we somehow commission someone at Stack Overflow to write something in exchange for reputation points? In exchange for money?  [Kickstarter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kickstarter)? A simple JavaScript editor could allow for blocks to be put next to each other, like this Klunky editor, then it could generate a URL with a bunch of gibberish at the end, which then causes the server to generate a single PNG, for instance.

The image could be linked directly from forums or copied to Imgur automatically by the Stack Exchange software. The URL of the image could be plugged back into the editor to allow modifications, etc.

The text labels in Klunky could use some work, too.

Or if Stack Exchange accepted data: URLs, it could generate an image that could be copied and pasted into the URL box without requiring a server at all. :)

Or [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). Or [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash). Or something. But I think a simple block-based editor would be sufficient for the vast majority of online schematic examples, rather than a full-fledged schematic capture program that allows you to draw wires manually and move components one pixel at a time and change all their parameters.

Here's an [HTML 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) image editor that generates images as data: URLs, for instance:

- http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/
- http://softwareas.com/ajaxjavascript-8-ways-to-create-graphics-on-the-fly

Data URLs can be converted into tinyurls!

http://preview.tinyurl.com/smallreddot

Comment: This is awesome Endolith. You brought the goods with your answer. I will try it out and will consider it as an easier option then my selected as it looks nicer also.

Answer (score 13):

Just learned (as of March 2012) of a new web-based schematic drawing tool called "[Scheme-It](http://www.digikey.com/schemeit)" that uses HTML5 to enable drawing of schematics online, and it also allows export to PNG & PDF formats.

[image: scheme-it screenshot]

Apparently it's supported by Digi-Key, I'm sure it's intended to drive you to buy components from them but there is no registration or anything required, no lock-in, and it seems to be very usable.  Within 60 seconds of visiting the site I'd dragged some components for a basic circuit & exported it as a PNG.

No simulation capabilities though -- I use LTSPICE for that, others have already covered LTSPICE in other answers.

Answer (score 12):

Some that I recommend for small projects and prototyping is [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/download/).

They are very good to convert the schematic to a prototype board. And very easy to use.

And the best, it's free!

[image][image]

Comment: Can you show an example of drawing a *schematic* in Fritzing?

Comment: @ThePhoton Done!

Comment: Sometimes it exits without any error message just right in the middle of design process.. :(

Comment: I've had a few problems with Fritzing on Linux. It seems to not like certain components (like strip board) and hangs for some time, particular when re-calculating complex layouts. But its nice for generating pix of simple stuff.

Answer (score 8):

Personally I don't like the traditional electronics schematics, because I'm normally making stuff for non engineers. So I use Photographs and a regular drawing program to label the components. Thought it may be of interest to people checking out this thread

[Posc Board http://sonodrome.co.uk/Pboard-01.png](http://sonodrome.co.uk/Pboard-01.png)

I like this method as it's easy to understand and quick to draw up. (obviously this picture comes with a key describing each label)

Comment: just curious: what drawing program did you use for the annotations?

Comment: It looks like an effective way to communicate to non-engineers, I normally only communicate with engineers, but point taken for non-engineers.

Comment: I used adobe illustrator CS4, but I'm sure any old drawing program would do the trick.

Comment: But that's a parts placement diagram, not a schematic.  The schematic is for explaining a circuit's operation, the parts diagram is for building a physical copy.

Comment: That's partly true, a schematic however still does not explain how a circuit operates, merely how it fits together and what value the components are. I'm merely suggesting the use of annotated photographs as it's a quick way to share circuits. Do we have to use abstract symbols in a world where high quality images are so easy to produce??

Comment: But how do you connect the parts to each other?  This isn't anything like a schematic.

Comment: I normally have a photo of the tracks too, unless it's single side surface mount. And No, you're right it's nothing like a schematic.
"Thought it may be of interest to people checking out this thread
" I just thought it was interesting when looking at sharing circuit designs, it's so easy to take a hi res image nowadays, and sometimes this can share a greater amount of detail for less effort.

Comment: I think it was nice to add to this thread and I applaud you for it. I could see this helping give others ideas, and that is what I wanted this thread for.

Comment: Also, this picture makes an awesome background for a phone.

Comment: @Jim - photo link broken as at January 16th 2012. It's a good idea to import pictures into the stack exchange system so the links don't break. (Maybe that feature was not available in Dec 09).

Comment: @Jim I know russell has already said something, but if you have this picture still it would be great if you could put it back in using the stack exchange system.

Comment: @Kellenjb Sorry I don't have the image anymore, I should have just uploaded it to the stack ex. However I posted this before I realised I could do that.

Comment: @Jim based off some of the other comments around it sounds like the image uploader was a very new thing at the time. So nothing to worry about.

Comment: Honourable mention for Crocodile Clips (https://youtu.be/r3kxzLxyRxw?t=147) which was popular in the UK a few decades ago. It was my first introduction to circuit design. No longer developed though.

Answer (score 8):

Could generate them in PostScript in conjunction with TeX?

> [pst-circ](http://pstcirc.free.fr/index.html) is a PSTricks package to draw electric and electronic circuits. It can be used either with TeX or LaTeX.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Check out this javascript program on google code. It's not ready to be used yet but it's getting close. It doesn't work in IE and it has some glitches. I wouldn't embed it in a web page yet, but you can use it separately. I'm not much of a javascript programmer but with some help we can create our own editor. It won't create waveforms though. It would be awesome if you  could somehow include spice models in the xml .I think that would be a little too much for javascript though. this is just for quick sketches.

http://code.google.com/p/webtronics/

Comment: Still needs work.  :D  Anything web-based that could output an image would be great, though.

Answer (score 6):

I use gEDA as well. gschem for schematics and PCB for printed circuit board
layout. As an open source example I did a remix of the ladyada Drawdio circuit.
The files and documentation are at http://tinyurl.com/bq8pq4

My PCB footprint library and various EDA automation scripts are at
http://www.luciani.org

Comment: gEDA is looking nicer, I think I may install it on my personal laptop soon.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind an online tool, may I sugest [easyEDA](http://easyeda.com/):

[image]

Also upverter and 123d circuits are online viable options.

Comment: used this for the first time recently, really easy to use and the 3D simulation is 1-click and looks really good. also direct integration with JLCPCB to buy the board.

Answer (score 6):

My personal favorites are:

1. EAGLE:

While this software from CADSoft does not have simulation capabilities, it is one of the best schematic/PCB design programs I have used. The libraries are quite good and the documentation is excellent.
Download link: http://www.cadsoftusa.com/download-eagle/
Image:
[image: EAGLE]

2. Multisim:

This program from National Instruments combines schematic and PCB design along with simulation to provide a very versatile tool for electronic engineering applications. Its libraries are great and simulations are quite accurate. Unfortunately, it comes at a slightly higher price, but is definitely worth it.
Link: http://www.ni.com/multisim/buy/
Image:
[image: Multisim]

3. Proteus:

This is one of my all-time top favorites, though it comes at quite a price. This is generally better for professional applications that require extensive tools, and applications where software price isn't an issue. Like Multisim, Proteus combines Schematic/PCB design with simulation, making it a very useful tool in the workplace.
Link: http://www.labcenter.com/index.cfm
Image:
[image: Proteus 8.1]

While these are probably my top picks, other options include:

- Altium: http://www.altium.com/en/products/altium-designer
- KiCAD: https://www.kicad.org/
- PCB123: http://www.sunstone.com/pcb-solutions/pcb-cad-tools/pcb123
- ExpressPCB: http://www.expresspcb.com/
- DIPtrace: http://diptrace.com/
- PCBArtist: http://pcb-artist.en.softonic.com/
- LTSpice: http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/
- Pspice: http://www.orcad.com/products/orcad-ee-designer/overview

There are loads more out there, and there's not really one that's better than all the others. Schematic/PCB design tools are really the type of thing you need to try out for yourself and decide which you prefer personally. Use what you're most comfortable with!

Comment: I suppose [TINA-TI](http://www.ti.com/tool/tina-ti) deserves a mention. It's free but somewhat crippled and one major version behind the non-free TINA, but it comes with most TI chips in its library, which for me makes it more useful out of the box than Linear's LTSpice.

Answer (score 5):

[MetaPost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaPost) has a library [MakeCirc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecirc) for making publication-style schematics.  Here is [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/makecirc/MakeCirc-en.pdf).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[gEDA](http://www.geda-project.org/) is a free and open source tool. The gEDA package includes a schematic editor, PCB layout editor, Gerber viewer, bill of materials (BOM) generation, etc.

It also has [a huge symbol library](http://www.gedasymbols.org/).

Check *[gEDA/PCB Stuff](http://www.delorie.com/pcb/)* for a bunch of projects designed using gEDA.

[image]

[A video game made using gEDA](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2008/meggy-jr-rgb/):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### [DesignSpark PCB](http://www.designspark.com/pcb)

I recently started to use it and have found that it works OK for whipping up quick circuits, etc.

It's by [RS Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS_Components) and does require registration at their website. However, the product appears to be free.

It will handle schematics as well as PCB, and it is supposed to do Gerber files as well.

Note I am not affiliated with RS Components in any way.

Answer (score 4):

I use DipTrace http://www.diptrace.com/ it has a schematic tool, schematic capture, PCB layout, back propagation, auto routing and most important of all a very good library.

Designing custom libraries are as easy as the schematic tool. The learning curve is smooth and one can pick up the essentials in about an hour or two.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to draw schematics not for PCB .
you can try DrawSCH,it can draw schematics online for free.
[Try it here](http://www.dz863.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[ViaDesigner](http://www.ViaDesigner.com) is free, easy-to-use schematic capture and simulation that you use in your browser. Public designs are free and you start paying if you want private, team or implementation features. ViaDesigner lets you combine analog, digital and mixed-signal circuits in a unified simulation environment that supports VHDL-AMS, SPICE, VHDL and Verilog design entry formats.

VHDL-AMS sounds pretty complicated but you don't need to learn how to write VHDL-AMS or SPICE models to use ViaDesigner. Instead, ViaDesigner comes with a set of high-level design wizards that generate useful mixed-signal circuits like: gain stages, filters, analog to digital converters, DAC, linear & switching regulators, etc. Example wizards can be found here: [ViaDesigner Wizards](http://www.viadesigner.com/viawizards/).

Here's some screenshots of the ViaDesigner schematic & simulation environment:

[image: ViaDesigner Schematic Screenshot]

[image: ViaDesigner Simulation Waveform Viewer]

Ultimately, ViaDesigner.com is focused on letting you design your own mixed-signal custom chips easily and cost-effectively. ViaDesigner will soon have a complete IC design flow in the cloud. This implementation design flow isn't free but the goal is to enable custom mixed-signal IC design, verification and fabrication for about $10,000. That's a lot of money but typical IC design flows can be anywhere from $100,000 to $1-million.

Yes, I work at ViaDesigner & these are my biased opinions about the ViaDesigner.com and the ViaDesigner software but still I'm pretty excited about what we are putting together.

Answer (score 2):

Loads. Most popular among hobbyists are probably [EAGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAGLE_%28program%29) (there is a free limited version which is probably good enough for what you are describing) and [KiCad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KiCad) (free and open source).

Answer (score 1):

[Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/) might be what you're looking for. It has most of the "common" components (different Arduinos, LCDs, LEDs etc...).

Answer (score 1):

I am providing you the complete list of 49 free electronics software which are used for the schematic and more electronics purposes.....

http://www.efytimes.com/e1/132694/Free-Software-On-Electronics

And on 50th tool which I have used, is Logisim. This tool provides the basic digital component to make any electronics circuit even microprocessor. This is the easiest tool which I have ever used.

Answer (score 1):

[EveryCircuit](https://everycircuit.com/) for absolute beginners. Actually a simulator rather than a schematic tool like KiCad/Altium. The advantage of EveryCircuit is that it animates current flow, which can be helpful when understanding the very basics. I'm surprised that it hasn't been mentioned yet.

I do believe though that as of writing, the user interface for EveryCircuit is quite "janky" (it actually drives me nuts) compared to [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) which actually my current favourite simulator.

Comment: Another great one, also with animations, is the Falstad circuit simulator.

Comment: Link for convenience of others: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Answer (score 0):

I use [FastStone capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) to post screen shots.

Here are the steps:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>
2. Drag the area I want to capture
3. It pops up the image
4. I click on ftp. It knows my domain and where to put it. It makes up a name based on the date. It copies the URL to the clipboard
5. I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> the URL to the insert picture icon

That's it. You still have to have a schematic on your computer, but this addresses a large part of your question.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: clearly a quick way to get it done when you are setup. I use multiple computers, many of them in a computer lab. I also like a solution I can quickly have working without installing software. If i set something up on one computer I think this may be the ticket.

Comment: I usually use alt-printscreen + mspaint + imageshack.us. Same effect as above, maybe slightly more steps to follow, but works on every version of windows without installing anything.

Comment: Stack Exchange now has a [network-wide pro account with imgur](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/).  Clicking the button above your answer will allow you to upload an image from your computer.  With this host, we won't loose images when other sites go down/out of business/expire.  Please don't host screenshots on your own site (or other image hosts, or anonymously on imgur).

Comment: @reemrevnivek, now when you link a picture from your own site it automatically takes it and uploads it with their account.

Comment: @mmccoo Do you still have a screen shot that you can post for us? Your current one doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @Kortuk > " I use multiple computers, many of them in a computer lab." -- I can't help but mention Synergy. Ever used it?

Answer (score 0):

There another interesting one - www.DoCircuits.com - real like schematics can be captured and shared.

Comment: Your answer is too brief. Can you give us more information about this site in your answer? Your goal should be to teach us about it.

Comment: Link appears to be broken now.