# Importing component library on Kicad

Tags: kicad, library

I'd like to import a component library that I downloaded into my Kicad. I am running the latest Kicad for Windows as shown below. I have added the directory containing the library into the library search path. I even copied the library in to the global library directory within the installation location. And the component does not show up in my library browser!!

The answer on a [similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18093/how-do-i-look-at-all-the-footprints-in-a-kicad-library) does not seem to work with this version of Kicad.

```
Application: kicad Version: (2015-01-16 BZR 5376)-product Release build wxWidgets: Version 3.0.0 (debug,wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,GCC 4.8.2,wx containers,compatible with 2.8) Platform: Windows 7 (build 7601, Service Pack 1), 64-bit edition, 64 bit, Little endian, wxMSW Boost version: 1.54.0
         USE_WX_GRAPHICS_CONTEXT=OFF
         USE_WX_OVERLAY=OFF
         KICAD_SCRIPTING=ON
         KICAD_SCRIPTING_MODULES=ON
         KICAD_SCRIPTING_WXPYTHON=ON
         USE_FP_LIB_TABLE=HARD_CODED_ON
         BUILD_GITHUB_PLUGIN=ON
         KICAD_USE_WEBKIT=OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I have to activate the library I want to use. Merely adding the library to my search path is not sufficient [1].

[1] https://forum.kicad.info/t/importing-component-library/574

Comment: I'd like to add that the BZR versions are up to 6129+ today. For the latest versions, see http://kicad-pcb.org/download/ . Why they haven't made a single "official" release since 2013, is beyond me.

Comment: Unless I am working on a legacy project, I have moved on to Altium CircuitMaker

Comment: I'd heard that [Altium CircuitMaker](http://www.altium.com/circuitmaker/overview) has a free version now. Only two projects can be closed-source at any time however. Anything else "goes to the cloud." Fine for hobbyists and "makers", not so good for companies and intellectual property.