# Drawing circuit schematics and export to TikZ

Tags: schematics, software

Is there any tool for drawing circuit schematics (by "mouse clicking") which exports to [TikZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ)?

Comment: It might be helpful to back up a bit and tell us what it is you are wanting to do. Why is it that you want to export to TikZ? We also have a pretty extensive list of schematic tools here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/good-tools-for-drawing-schematics

Comment: Currently I use TikZ to draw simple circuits for problem sheets. I am just looking for a graphical interface where I can select components with the mouse, drag them around etc. which produces good TikZ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no short answer to your question. To begin with, `TikZ` is a part of the `(La)TeX` ecosystem. That being said, it's a WYMIWYG (What You Mean Is What You Get) not WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) kind of thing, so basically the very spirit in which it was created goes against 'drag-and-drop' kind of philosophy.

If you are using a library specifically designed for drawing circuits (e.g. `circuitikz` or the `circuit` library provided by `TikZ` itself), I think you've run out of luck.

If, on the contrary, you have no problem drawing the shapes and then want to manipulate them, you can use [`Inkscape`](http://inkscape.org/) and export to `TikZ` with a [plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/). I have used it, you get working, albeit suboptimal `TikZ` code, to say the least.

On a more personal note, I believe you should learn `TikZ`. Once you master it, you will not need the rather complicated approach with `Inkscape` and will have very readable code. You can try [TeX.StackExcahge](http://tex.stackexchange.com) if stuck - the community is very friendly and responsive. I know it first hand, because I'm part of it. `;)`