# What software tool was used to draw these circuit schematics?

Tags: schematics, drawing

I was reading online and found this site: http://www.cppsim.com/

I was very curious how this professor drew all these circuit diagrams in his lecture notes (such as this one: http://www.cppsim.com/CommCircuitLectures/lec9.pdf). They just look very, very good.

An example is shown below:

[image: circuit diagram]

---

To be more specific about what I mean, by "publication quality" I mean the following:

- The software must output vector graphics, such as eps, or windows meta files.
- It would be good to have control over the style of the graphics, such the style of the components, line width, figure size, etc.
- It would be good to have a graphical user interface. I understand LaTeX is very powerful but it's just too painful to write a 100 line script to generate a circuit diagram.

So in short, I'm not really looking for a schematic capture program. I'm looking for a program that can generate pretty circuit schematic illustrations so that I can put them in papers and presentations.

(I am aware of other posts on this forum, such as this one: [Good tools for drawing schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/good-tools-for-drawing-schematics).  None of the software mentioned in that post seems to get you publication quality figures.)

Comment: Did you try writing to the professor and asking?  Michael H. Perrott? They're from here http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-976-high-speed-communication-circuits-and-systems-spring-2003/ and the course logo looks like it was made the same way

Answer (score 20):

I'll take a guess though I don't know for sure. The key words here are *publication quality* and *professor*. LaTeX does a very nice job when used in conjunction with [CircuitTikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/circuitikz/). LaTeX is very much used for typesetting documents in the university setting.

[image: Examples]

Comment: +1 - I was thinking it was probably Latex too, would make sense in a math heavy document written by a professor.

Comment: +1 for specifically answering his question of what made those SPECIFIC schematics

Comment: [Page 5](http://www.cppsim.com/CommCircuitLectures/lec9.pdf) doesn't make LaTeX likely.

Comment: None of the original document makes LaTeX likely. The font, the layout, etc... very strongly suggests it has been made with a basic windows presentation software, and this is confirmed by looking within the PDF data where you can find occurrences of the "Microsoft PowerPoint" string. Although CircuitTikZ may be a good choice for building diagrams, it has clearly not been used for this specific document.

Answer (score 10):

This really looks like xcircuit to me. It is a very simple program which outputs ps or eps files with an optional LaTeX text mode, which will output a .tex file with text overlays for the postscript output. Take a look: http://opencircuitdesign.com/xcircuit/

Answer (score 2):

For the circuit / schematic drawing tools, the most advanced and usable software tools are not free:

1. [multiSIM](http://www.ni.com/multisim/) but it is very expensive, but you can get a student trial version for download and use but this trial version has some less features. multiSIM comes with Simulator.
2. [Proteus](http://www.labcenter.com/index.cfm) which is less expensive than multiSIM. You may download a trial version. Proteus also comes with a Simulator.
3. [CADsoft EAGLE Layout Editor](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/download-eagle/?language=en) which is paid as well as free, But it has no simulator.
4. [Electronic Work Bench](http://www.electronicsworkbench.com/products/proprod_dl.html) Free for students and paid for Professionals. Comes with Simulator.
5. [TinyCAD](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=free%20schematic%20capture&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CE4QFjAA&url=http://tinycad.sourceforge.net/&ei=LrYtUIz3KNK30gGM_4D4Cw&usg=AFQjCNF-ukXqqkwKBXIXx0aCkX4P5tgIiA) Free and open source software without simulator.
6. [DipTrace](http://www.diptrace.com/) Free as well as paid software without simulator.
7. [Altium](http://www.altium.com/) Very expensive tool without Simulator.

There are so many other software tools. Free software has fewer features and expensive software gives a lot of features.

So, the final choice is yours, you may try TinyCAD first as it is free and open source, than go to the other options.

Comment: Proteus Simulator is good; but many times it runs in sim for me back on actual hardware horrible fail. Nice suggestions

Comment: I personaly use multiSIM, and i like this software, due to its accuracy and correct response, i had design so many circuits in multiSIM and it gives almost 95% correct response, 5% error may you get due to variation of electronics components

Comment: I can't vote this answer down, but this isn't what the op asked for. He wanted a program to create vector diagrams for publication. None of those programs do that. Those programs are all CAD applications.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is hand drawn in something like CorelDraw. There are many imperfections, which I would not expect from a dedicated schematic drawing app:

- 3-way wire dots have a few pixel inconsistencies
- arrow tips are not centered on their respective lines
- current source arrow is not centered in its circle