# Microelectronic Circuits Sedra Smith (drawing tool)

Tags: mosfet, tools, drawing, website

I'm looking for the tool used in the reference "Microelectronic Circuits" (or similar) to draw the circuits. e.g. For the n-channel enhancement-type (circuit symbol c).[image: MOSFET]

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38134/anyone-knows-what-software-tool-is-used-to-draw-these-circuit-schematics

Comment: Finally, find this: https://www.digikey.com/schemeit