# Which tool is being used to create the following figure?

Tags: schematics, drawing

I am trying to determine the circuit drawing tool that is used to create figures in some papers I come across every once in a while. The tool is able to create some very slick-looking diagrams/schematics. Here is one example:

[image]

I like everything about the schematic above -- in particular, I really like the way the MOSFETs look and the ground symbol. Whenever I see schematics drawn with this tool in papers, I am always impressed with the way it looks in the paper (even if the author's interpretation of their results is not quite right).

In another similar [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/38134), *xcircuit* was given as a possibility, but the *xcircuit* drawn figures I've seen don't look anything at all like the example above.

Comment: It is possible that they are templates in some office suite, not entirely improbable. Otherwise, no idea.

Comment: Probably draw by a person in a graphics package. I've achieved similar graphics using little more than MS Paint.

Comment: My guess is, it has been drawn in Adobe Illustrator. Although other tools with SVG capabilities could do the same.

Comment: The error in the top circle of S2 implies that it's hand drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xfig** (available in Linux) could approach this style.
An example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [Cirkuit\$^1\$ together with Circuit Macros](http://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/cirkuit.html) if you're into LaTex.

[image]
\$^1\$ Reminds me of a Power Systems professor (I think he was from Romania) I had back in University, who would pronounce "circuit" as sare-kweet.