# What software do people use to make digital circuit schematics?

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, simulation, drawing

What software do people use to make electronic circuit schematics like [this](http://www.glacialwanderer.com/_blog/blog2011/03_March/motorSensor.png) or similar.I tried using multisim but it seems to miss most chips.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/good-tools-for-drawing-schematics may be worth a look

Comment: That particular schematic is most likely done in [Eagle CAD](http://www.cadsoftusa.com). It's a very popular CAD software, so you'll find a lot of component libraries.

Comment: m.Alin: make that an answer!

Comment: The schematic you linked to looks like it has been created with eagle (suggested by m.Alin). I find eagle easy to use, and it's really easy to create your own components with different package options. If you just need a schematic, just go ahead and try it, there is a limited free version available here: http://www.cadsoftusa.com/download-eagle/?language=en&lang=en

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Actually, this question should be closed. It's an exact duplicate as the one PeterJ linked to. I flagged to close it.

Comment: The linked question asks for more: free, and support for simulation, and does not show a specific circuit diagram that it wants to be created. IMO 'eagle' is the single answer to this question, while that other question has a much broader answer.

Comment: Altium (commercial) and Eagle (free) are two I know.

Comment: Checkout [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/good-tools-for-drawing-schematics) thread first