# Open source software for schematics

Tags: software

I am looking for an open source (or just free) software for creating electric schemes. It would be better if your program could do other schematics (for instance, installation schemes of physical experiments) and if it would be crossplatform.

Comment: Please see this question, "*[Good Tools for Drawing Schematics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/1024/14004)*", which addresses your question. Also, in English the more commonly used term is "schematics" rather than "schemes".

Comment: @AnindoGhosh this question adds that the software should be _open source_.

Comment: @CamilStaps Yes, that is why I pointed at that question. Several of the answers do refer to open source software, such as KiCAD.

Comment: Thank you for answers. How can I close this question?

Comment: @cheremushkin don't worry about it, users with sufficient reputation will close it soon