# What is the best program for designing circuit diagrams

Tags: schematics

I am trying to find a free program for designing circuit diagrams. Is Autodesk's Eagle program any good or is that just for designing PCBs. I've had a look at Microsoft Visio but I don't really want to spend $20 a month. I'm looking for a program that is for making basic circuit diagrams that have symbols.
Thanks.

Comment: too subjective, but look into KiCAD

Comment: Visio is *not* a circuit design program even if it has some of the symbols.

Comment: See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/good-tools-for-drawing-schematics

Comment: Give EXPRESSPCB a look.  Simple but free.

Comment: I second ExpressSch, part of the ExpressPCB family, for schematic capture. Easy to use, easy to make up your own symbols if needed. https://www.expresspcb.com/expresssch/  I use Eagle myself as I then create PCBs from the schematics, examples can be seen here http://www.crossroadsfencing.com/BobuinoRev17

Comment: The is no best without requirements.  http://www.pcbweb.com/  except free and simple in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only schematics entry and free, then I think you only have 2 well supported options: Eagle or LTspice. Free Eagle is an entry level full eCAD program, so it also supports schematic entry and does it well with a huge online library.

LTspice is the other option. It's a simulation program but simulations need schematic entry too. LTspice probably has a slightly easier learning curve. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

At our university, UG students use the open source circuit drawing tool [Xcircuit](http://opencircuitdesign.com/xcircuit/)

This might be what the OP is looking for since unlike Eagle and LTspcice it is purely a tool to create schematics.

The software is compatible with Latex and the software produces a .tex file that can be added to a Latex source file to give annotations and captions that are dynamic and not frozen into the schematic.

Fair Warning: The software is buggy and keeps crashing randomly. Be sure to save your work frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a drawing tool without any circuit design features (like Visio), try [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), the general purpose open-source vector graphics editor. There are many free electrical symbols libraries and extensions for Inkscape, e.g. [Electrical symbols library](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Electrical_symbols_library.svg), or [circuitSymbols](https://inkscape.org/~fsmMLK/%E2%98%85circuitsymbols).

Comment: I use Inkscape for drawings but wouldn't dream of using it for a schematic. Wiring would have to be redrawn and checked every time a component is moved. Hopeless.

Comment: True, but if Visio is good enough, Inkscape will also do the job ("making basic circuit diagrams that have symbols").

Comment: Visio does have attachment points though and the wires will remain attached to some extent. I've never tried using it for schematics but I imagine it will move the wiring to the incorrect nodes in an attempt to be clever.